# Visual Studio 2012 update 2 shows Windows App Certification Kit warning

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation

I've installed Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 offline mode, because I've been working on intra network.

I made offline package with argument '/layout'. But with this package, I got a warning message like 'Windows App Certification Kit blah blah...' when finishing installation.

Is there any problem with this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. 
See answer of SteveHall in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/45e91b4e-71c5-4fad-8626-00c37c2b5e02